# Using the same LSTMCell in two different RNNs - TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to create a siamese LSTM network, meaning that 2 separate inputs go into an RNN that uses the same LSTM weights.

This is what I have so far

```
def run_through_siamese_lstm(left_input, right_input, left_length, right_length, lstm_cell)
    left_output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, left_input, left_length, dtype=tf.float32)
    right_output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstm_cell, right_input,right_length, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Extract the last output
    left_output = tf.transpose(left_output, [1, 0, 2])
    left_last_output = tf.gather(left_output, int(left_output.get_shape()[0]) - 1)

    right_output = tf.transpose(right_output, [1, 0, 2])
    right_last_output = tf.gather(right_output, int(right_output.get_shape()[0]) - 1)

    return tf.exp(-tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(tf.subtract(left_last_output, right_last_output)), axis=1))

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(n_hidden, initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer,
                                    forget_bias=forget_bias)
    left_batch = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, max_seq_length, embedding_size])
    left_seq_length = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])

    right_batch = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, max_seq_length, embedding_size])
    right_seq_length = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None])



    similarity = run_through_siamese_lstm(left_batch, right_batch, left_seq_length, right_seq_length, lstm_cell)
    .
    .
```

Code throws an exception on the `run_through_siamese_lstm` with the following output

> ValueError: Variable rnn/lstm_cell/weights already exists, disallowed. Did you mean to set reuse=True in VarScope?

I tried setting `reuse=True` but it didn't work... Any ideas how to go about that?

Comment: where did you specified reuse=True?

Comment: in the LSTMCell init

Comment: with two separated init? one for the first tf.nn.dynamic_rnn, without reuse, and one for the second, with reuse?

Comment: nope, i created only one cell as you can see

Comment: you need to create two cells the first one without reuse=True, the second one with reuse=True

Comment: @ArnaudDeBroissia
Creating 2 different cells and the second one with reuse=True will make them share weights?
Do i need to set the initializer on the second? the n_hidden too?

I suggest you post an aswer with code example, I will accept it if it works